# vb2013 exit from local sub closes form

Tags: visual-studio-2013, basic

I have a local sub that allows the user to move a row of a datagridview, triggered by a button click. The sub works fine in debugger but when it exits control is transfered to the calling form, i.e. the current form is closed. This also happens when no row is moved, i.e. when one of the abort conditions on entrance are met. Simply: exiting this sub will close the form!?!

```
Private Sub btnMove_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMove.Click
    Dim rowToGo As DataGridViewRow
    Dim rtgIndex As Integer = 0
    If (dgvAuftrag.RowCount <= 1) or (dgvAuftrag.CurrentRow Is Nothing) Then
        Beep()
        Exit Sub
    End If
    rowToGo = dgvAuftrag.CurrentRow
    rtgIndex = rowToGo.Index + 1
    If (rtgIndex >= dgvAuftrag.RowCount) Then rtgIndex = 0
    Try
        dgvAuftrag.Rows.Remove(rowToGo)
        dgvAuftrag.Rows.Insert(rtgIndex, rowToGo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        IssueErrorMessage(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

All other local subs and functions work normal, just this one behaves strange. Any ideas how to fix/avoid this bug?

Comment: Add an event handler for the form's FormClosing event.  Set a breakpoint on it and look at the call stack.

Comment: Thank you Hans. Call stack shows that `FormClosing` has been called by the `Sub ShowDialog`. Strange because this is a `Overload` in order to be able to pass parameters to the form. All it does is to copy the parameters to local form vars and to `Call MyBase.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: ShowDialog() is rather relevant to the problem, that info belongs in the question.  Search for code that assigns the form's DialogResult property.  And look at the button's DialogResult property.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution of the problem but a functioning workaround based on the sugestion of Hans. I have introduced a global boolean var named OKtoExit which is intialized to false.

```
private OKtoExit as boolean = false
```

Then I have a new FormClose event handler that checks that var. If OKtoExit is false then e.Cancel = true and the handler exits. The regular Exit functions (Save and Quit) set OKtoExit to true, any other code leaves the values unchanged.

```
Private Sub Current_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    If Not exitOK Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

As I said, this is just a workaround that has the same effect as a normal functioning VB-Code. I would appreciate if somebody could present a real solution!

Answer (score 0):

After many months I discovered the true reason for the problem and I must give all credits to Hans Passant: I had a button on one of the first forms that had the Dialog Result property set to Cancel. This was a really beautyful button so many other buttons in the appliaction were a copy of this first button where I just modified the label. Thus they all led to the unwanted behavior that a form was closed as soon as a user clicked one of them no matter what the label said... After months I discovered that just by chance. Thanks to Hans again, I obviously overlooked his last hint "And look at the button's DialogResult property."!

Comment: While this is a nice story, you should make your answers as concise as possible. Perhaps you should quote what [Hans Passant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) said and leave it at that :-)

Comment: I don't know Gediminas Masaitis where you have been brought up. In my country it is good manners to say Thank you if somebody helped you. If you think it could have been done shorter, and you are probably right, please leave me your email address, you can then write the postings for me in the future...

Comment: You should check out [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and answers at SO meta. The general consensus here is that "hi", "thanks" and such is just fluff which gets in the way of readability and conciseness of answers. My personal belief is actually a bit different from that, but I'm just advising you to follow the site's guidelines